# Can I get exact coordinates of London zones and use them in code?

Tags: google-maps

I'm working with Google Maps API. I found that there are already drawn London transport shapes and London borough shapes. Is it possible to get exact coordinates how it's done and even recreate these shapes using API?

London Transport Map - https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1eIjWEQyO-PchgJUttxBBkYqvPxE&ll=51.49280340511744%2C-0.17372399999999288&z=11

Borough
https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/London+Borough+of+Islington

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [London Transportation Map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1eIjWEQyO-PchgJUttxBBkYqvPxE&ll=51.49280340511744%2C-0.17372399999999288&z=11) is a "Google MyMap", those if public can have their data exported as KML/KMZ and shown on a [Google Maps Javascript API v3 KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer)

1. Go to [the map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1eIjWEQyO-PchgJUttxBBkYqvPxE&ll=51.49280340511744%2C-0.17372399999999288&z=11)
2. click on the three vertical dots [image: three vertical dots]
3. click on "Download KML" [image: Download KML]
4. Select "Keep data up to date with network link (only useable online)."[image: Keep data up to date with network link]
5. unzip that file and get the link out of it (it is a zip file containing a KML file called doc.kml): 
   http://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml?mid=1eIjWEQyO-PchgJUttxBBkYqvPxE
6. use that as the URL for a KML layer ([proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/memmus8h/))

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
  layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    map: map,
    url: "http://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml?mid=1eIjWEQyO-PchgJUttxBBkYqvPxE"
  })

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

As for the Borough of Islington map, that is a "real" Google Map", you can't get that data from Google, you need to find another source.